# obj is always None in MyModelAdmin's has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=obj)

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to not allow deleting some instances of a model in the admin. In order to do so, I overrided the `has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=obj)` of MyModelAdmin:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):

        # try to get obj to check if it can be deleted
        # but obj is always None

        return super(UserProfileAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj=obj)
```

but when I select some instances in my admin and apply the delete action, the obj variable in `has_delete_permission` is always None.

Anybody could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. Look at the Django ticket here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11383

Comment: Sure. Write your own custom action to delete objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gist to work around the problem: https://gist.github.com/rudyryk/4190318